# Using C# classes with Java

Tags: c#, java

Is there any way to use **C#** classes (of a project) into another **java** project?

Or any other possible solution for this (like conversion - example: [Java Language Conversion Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kwtxa08%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

Since now, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at 'native' modifier

Comment: Is there a paticular library that exists in C# that you want a Java equivalent? That might get better answers if it's an external/public library.

Comment: Are you looking for a one time C# -> Java, or do you want to be able to maintain portions of the program in C# over a long period of time? What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Look up the Java Native Interface. It allows java to talk to .dlls, and thus you can make java wrappers that call code in .dlls written in C#.

Comment: James, Actually I want to use c# classes into the both projects (c# and Java, at the same time). Because the projects are related..

Comment: @CaioOliveira Have you considered moving the shared functionality to a service?

Answer (score 0):

**C# -> Java**

CodePorting C#2Java is a web-based tool for converting C# applications and source code into Java. (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9789645d-9b31-4033-bcb1-53dc5ff58e05)

Google give you several options
https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+to+Java